# delete lvm volume

Tags: lvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase Linux Partition dynamically?](https://serverfault.com/questions/355304/increase-linux-partition-dynamically)

There are 3 lvm volume on Science Linux 6.1 x86. I want to remove one volume and give the amount to /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root.

```
[root@localhost /]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       50G   38G  9.1G  81% /
tmpfs                 504M  924K  503M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   68M  392M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                       96G  7.7G   83G   9% /home

umount /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
lvremove /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
umount /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
lvextend -L +96G /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Please let me know these command work correctly.

Comment: You are going to need to do something to resize your root filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to unmount your root filesystem (and in fact, you *can't*).  After you have resized the LV on which it resides, you can simply do `resize2fs` on it.

Comment: Teddy/ I booted with Livecd

Comment: @WindStory, mark this as the answer by clicking the check mark underneath the grey "1" above. We don't edit titles here, that's not how we play.